# mod-tile: How to set up two independent tileservers?

Tags: tiles, server, mod-tile

Reading mod-tile and rendered documentation, especially the commented lines in the `renderd.conf` file, it seems to be possible, with the same renderd and mod-tile, to define two different style sheets that query two different databases and write tiles to two different folders.

But I couldn't find exactly how this worked. Does someone have an idea or link explaining this?